# What type of power connector is this?

Tags: plug

I have one of those portable 16 Ah car jump starters that I want to use as a power pack for some 12v stepper motors. Rather than canabilize this plug, I am wondering if someone can tell me what it is called so I can see if I can find an unwired one on ebay or something to use. My current needs are very low at around 1 amp.

Many Thanks

[image: car Jump Starter Connection]

Comment: Nice clear picture showing the view of the connector. It would be helpful if you could post an additional picture straight on from the end of the connector. Then show several dimensions including outside diameter of the round shaped post part of the connector and the center to center dimension between the "O" and "D" shaped posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'ts an EC3 connector, available at [dhgate](https://www.dhgate.com/product/ec3-ec3-0-golden-plug-female-male-bullet/251670032.html).

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your connector us very similar to the Universal Mate-N-Lock type of connector sold by TE Connectivity.

[image]

*<sup>([Source of picture and product page](http://www.te.com/usa-en/product-1-480698-0.html))</sup>*

Unfortunately that series has flats on both pin barrels and they are on the wrong side.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the pointers, I was able to jump from what you suggested and it looks like an Ec3 connector

Comment: Please edit this into your question instead of answering yourself.

Comment: Apologies, how do I mark it as answered if it is in the edit itself?

Comment: @Janka - What is wrong with answering your own question? That is encouraged here, provided it's new information. Also, it does't make sense to me to put the answer to a question in the question.

Comment: Oh? Wasn't aware the policy at EE SE is different. I found it more useful if someone had found the solution herself, I could read it in the question already. Maybe both? **Makes the obviously correct answer stand out more.**

Comment: You can answer your own question, this is appropriate. Infact you can write a question and answer it all at the same time if you desire.